# Confused With New Order Status in Magento 2.0.6 by using with any Payment Gateway

Tags: magento2, payment, order-status, magento-2.0.6

I am new In Magento 2 platform. Can anyone please tell me with proper clarification what should be the exact order status for the order state `New Order` while buying through any Payment Gateway

Clarification with code description will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this below blog for your clarification, may be it will help you.

http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-payment-methods/

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5860

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348473/set-order-status-to-pending-by-default-when-no-option-is-selected

or if you want to change order status.
[Change Order status to processing automatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64919/change-order-status-to-processing-automatically)